# Why I am getting these errors? AttributeError: can't set attribute

Tags: python, python-decorators

I am trying to test my properties but it's not working and I have no idea why.

```
import smtplib

class EmailService(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self._sender=None
        self._receiver=None
        self._message=None

    @property
    def sender(self):
        return self._sender

    @sender.getter
    def sender(self, sender):
        self._sender = sender

    @property
    def receiver(self, receive):
        return self._sender

    @receiver.getter
    def receiver(self, receiver):
        self._receiver = receiver

    @property
    def message(self, message):
        return self._message

    @message.getter
    def message(self, message):
        self._message = message




def main():
    smtp=EmailService()

    smtp.sender="kevin"
    smtp.receiver="alvin"
    print(smtp.message +"   "+ smtp.sender+"   " + smtp.receiver )

if __name__=="__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: You wrote `@sender.getter` instead of `@sender.setter`.

Answer (score 1):

The methods wrapped with `@property` are already your `getter`s.

So replace `@receiver.getter` with `@receiver.setter` to make the corresponding methods `setter`s

Answer (score 1):

> AttributeError: can't set attribute

This is happening because you're trying to set the `sender` and `receiver` attributes but you don't have setters for them.

You need to replace:

- `@sender.getter` with `@sender.setter`
- `@receiver.getter` with `@receiver.setter`
- `@message.getter` with `@message.setter`

The `@property` decorator makes that method the getter. The setters need to be in the format - `@<property_name>.setter`

So fix the incorrect `@<name>.getter`s with `@<name>.setter`s.